# JQuery HoverIntent for non-nested menu content

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I'm using JQuery HoverIntent to create a menu.

Here is the basic structure of my HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li id="sh-zone-menu-sub-services" class="submenu"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li id="sh-zone-menu-sub-support" class="submenu"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li id="sh-zone-menu-sub-contact" class="submenu"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="sh-zone-menu-sub-services-target" class="submenu-content">Services Content</div>
<div id="sh-zone-menu-sub-support-target" class="submenu-content">Support Content</div>
<div id="sh-zone-menu-sub-contact-target" class="submenu-content">Contact Content</div>
```

And here's the JQuery Code:

```
var $_ = jQuery;
$_(document).ready(function(){  

    function showSubMenu()
    {
        var source_id = $_(this).attr("id");
        $_(this).addClass("showsubmenu");
        $_("#"+source_id+"-target").show();
    }

    function hideSubMenu()
    {
        var source_id = $_(this).attr("id");
        $_(this).removeClass("showsubmenu");
        $_("#"+source_id+"-target").hide();
    }

    var subMenuConfig = 
    {
        interval: 100,
        sensitivity: 4,
        over: showSubMenu,
        timeout: 300,
        out: hideSubMenu 
    };

    $_("ul li.submenu").hoverIntent(subMenuConfig);
});
```

Everything works ok, but when the menu content is revealed and I try to hover over it, it disappears.

The way the HTML code was configured previously, the submenu-content DIVs were nested within the LI tags, and this worked ok i.e. with hover of menu link and content. However, I was having issues with positioning for IE (because the menu content spans a large portion of the page), so I needed to take them out of LI tags.

The way I have it now works ok for IE (CSS position-wise), but hoverIntent is not working.

Is there a way to use hoverIntent when my menu content is not nested within the LI tags?!

Thanks.

Comment: Check out: http://www.brandammo.co.uk/blog/2011/02/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu-with-easing-and-hoverintent-navidropdown-1-0 this give a full example.

Answer (score 1):

I know you posted this question a while ago and I have limited experience with the hoverIntent plugin, but here's what I know from looking at the code. The mouseenter and mouseleave events are bound to the object you bind hoverIntent to. The code in hoverIntent that binds to your object is:

```
return this.bind('mouseenter', handleHover).bind('mouseleave', handleHover);
```

So if you lave a ul and you bind to the li elements, something like this:

```
$("ul#ReportNav li").hoverIntent(config);
```

After the popup happens (displaying more elements from the ul) it doesn't fire the mouseleave event when you hover over the popup, because all of the elements in the popup are children of the ul.

So... if you have say...  a div wrapper with a div inside it as the the hover trigger, you want to just bind hoverIntent with the right syntax and it works fine (everything in the popup is a child of the hovered element):

```
<div id="ListContainer">
<div id="ListTableContainer">
<!-- anything you want -->
</div>
</div>

$("div#ListContainer div#ListTableContainer").css({ 'opacity': '0' });
$("div#ListContainer").hoverIntent(config);
```

I was searching for something similar and kept coming across this question. Thought I would answer it.